# Sorting table count by sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql server that contain the following fields

```
firstname,id,affID
```

the affID is an id of other user.

lets say I have this records

```
firstname     id    affID
bob            1     2        
someone        2     3
bob2           3     2 
baaroz         4     3
lastman        5     2
```

I want to make a query that show me the firstname,id and the count of affID for this id in other users order by this count.

So in the end the output should like this

```
firstname  id     count(number of this id in affID of other users)
someone    2            3
bob2       3            2
bob        1            0
baaroz     4            0
lastman    5            0
```

so far I make this query that return me the number of affID for each id

```
SELECT affID, count(affID) FROM Users group by affID
```

What is the right query for the output that mention above?

Comment: take your query, and join it to another query that is getting the names. (join by id)

Comment: I just play with your example and it looks perfect,dont know what is the problem,could it be the fields type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a subquery to get the count and then join to your table:

```
select u1.firstname,
  u1.id,
  coalesce(u2.total, 0) total
from users u1
left join
(
  SELECT affID, count(affID) Total
  FROM Users 
  group by affID 
) u2
  on u1.id = u2.affID
order by u2.total desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/016ca/8)

Comment: I can see it works on your example but I get total 0 for all users in my sql server

Comment: @baaroz Can you expand the dataset in the sql fiddle?

Comment: hi @bluefeet, I played with your code in it looks perfect,don't know why it's not working in my sql server.

Comment: when I remove the coalesce it return null in total of all users

Comment: @baaroz the `coalesce` replaced the `null` values with the zeros for the `ids` that are not in the subquery.

Comment: My mistake I used the wrong field ,it working great,thanks man for this smart answer :)

Comment: @baaroz I am glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a self-join to get the counts for each user, and left outer join to map them back to all users..

This query gives a count of affected users for each user that has affect other users:

```
SELECT U.id                           -- This is the ID of the user that affected others
     , Count(U2.id) as Cnt            -- This is the Count 
  FROM Users U
  INNER JOIN User U2 
          ON U.AffUserId = U2.id
 GROUP BY U.id
```

Then you will need to do a final LEFT OUTER JOIN to then map this aggregated data to **all** users in your table (i.e. even those that have not affected anybody)

```
SELECT Usr.firstName
     , Usr.id
     , ISNULL(Ctbls.Cnt, 0) as [Count]
  FROM Users Usr
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT U.id, Count(U2.id) as Cnt
      FROM Users U
      INNER JOIN User U2 
              ON U.AffUserId = U2.id
      GROUP BY U.id) CTbls
    ON Usr.id = Ctbls.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your ID values for baaroz and lastman shoud not be "1" but should be "4" and "5", respectively.  If that's true, then I believe that I understand your questions and all you need to do is add

```
"ORDER BY Count(AffUserId) DESC"
```

to the end of your query.

(Since the Id and the user name appear to be unique, you can just add the user name to your group by.  It's redundant, but easier than using a subquery and joining the table back to itself.)